# segmentation fault in structure pointer i c

Tags: c

below is my c program giving me segmentation fault,I don't know why. further sizeof (struct node1*) is giving answer 4 ,and sizeof (struct node1) is giving 12 . please explain me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node{
        int i;
        int j;
};

struct node1{
        int *a;
        int *b;
        struct node *n;
};

int main()
{
        struct node1 *nn;
        nn=(struct node1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
        nn->n->i=5;
        printf("\nsize is %d  -- %p -- %p %d\n",sizeof (struct node1*),*nn,nn,nn->n->i);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not allocated `nn->n`.

Comment: after allocation I got answer :size is 4  -- (nil) -- (nil) 138850328 !!

Comment: Yeah... `printf` doesn't know how to print `struct`s, but you are passing it one and telling it is a pointer. Better read an introductory C book or try some simpler examples first.

Answer (score 2):

You segfault because the 'n' member of 'node1' struct is not allocated.
Use malloc on nn->n after the first allocation.

```
struct node1 *nn;

nn=(struct node1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
nn->n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
//now nn->n is allocated you can set a value in nn->n->i
nn->n->i=5;
```

Don't forget the Free call before the "return 0"

```
free(nn->n);
free(nn);
return 0;
```